# Call a timestamp function on every row PHP

Tags: javascript, php, mysql

Here is my script:

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
    function getTimeStamp() {
       var now = new Date();
       return (  + now.getHours() + ':'
                     + ((now.getMinutes() < 10) ? 
 ("0" + now.getMinutes()) : (now.getMinutes()))       +      
 ':' + ((now.getSeconds() < 10) ? ("0" + now
                     .getSeconds()) : (now.getSeconds())));
    }
    function setTime() {
    document.getElementById('field').value = getTimeStamp();
    }
     </script>
```

HTML code:
        
        
         
         Frequency
       Run Time Schedule
       Duration
       SLA
        Type
       Title
        Actual Start
       Actual End
        Remark
        Done by

```
  <th align="center">


  </th>

  </tr>
  </thead>

<table>
td align="center"><?php echo $row['frequency']?></td>
<td align="center"><?php echo $row['rts']?></td>
<td align="center"><?php echo $row['duration']?></td>
<td align="center"><?php echo $row['sla']?></td>
<td align="center"><?php echo $row['type']?></td>
<td align="center"><?php echo $row['title']?></td>

<td>
<input id="field" type="text" name="field" value="" readonly size="11" />
<button type="button" onclick="setTime();">Get Time</button>
</td>
</table>
```

i want to add an actual start time and end time on every row with the press of button on the function, but the problem is only the first field only outputs the time, nothing happens when i press get time on other column and rows.

Comment: Not enough info to help. Please add code showing how/where/what you post to your PHP file. And post the relevant part of the PHP file for parsing said data and posting it to the DB.

Comment: The "id" attribute has to be unique on the page. You can't use an ID more than once. You need to use a class for this.

Answer (score 0):

In HTML, we can set only one id in one page thats why whenever you click on "Get Time" button, its only update first input button. So please add unique id for each row.

Comment: is there a way to shorten up the code. because my table have 100 rows meaning i have to do 100 function for the start time and 100 function for the end time?

Comment: You can pass id as variable in setTime();

Answer (score -1):

Check it

```
// You've written here getPassword()
function getpassword(){
var dt=new Date(), h=dt.getHours(), m=dt.getMinutes(), s=dt.getSeconds(),
date = new Date();
var h = dt.getHours();
var m = dt.getMinutes();
var s = dt.getSeconds();

document.getElementById("time").value=h + ':' + m + ':' + s;
}


</script>

<td align="right" width="180"><span class="style33"> start time :&nbsp;</span></td><td  align="left">
                <input type="text" id="time" readonly="readonly" name="time" /></td>
<script type="text/javascript">

function changeText(){
  var dt=new Date(), h=dt.getHours(), m=dt.getMinutes(), s=dt.getSeconds(),
date = new Date();
var h = dt.getHours();
var m = dt.getMinutes();
var s = dt.getSeconds();

document.getElementById("time1").value=h + ':' + m + ':' + s;
}



</script>


<td align="right" width="180"><span class="style33">  End time :&nbsp;</span></td><td align="left">
                <input type="text" id="time1" name="time1" /></td></tr>
```